Understanding `impl dyn Trait`

I can't wrap my head around the second impl block.  In my understanding, impl is typically used to implement a trait/methods on a concrete type like a struct.  However, what does it mean to implement method on a trait object?
Additionally, I'm confused about the role of lifetimes in this context. Could someone explain the concept of impl trait objects with lifetimes ?

trait Trait{
    fn f(&self);
}
impl Trait for bool {
    fn f(&self){
        print!("2");
    }
}
impl<'a> dyn Trait + 'a{
    fn f(&self){
        print!("1");
    }
}

I've consulted resources like The Rust Book, Rust Nomicon, and YouTube tutorials, but I'm still struggling to explain the output with confidence.

The first and second question are related and probably can stay in the same question. The third is not. Please ask one question in each post. I guess they all come from the same Rust Quiz, but this does not mean they can be in the same Stack Overflow question.

I was not aware of Rust Quiz. Thanks for that. I was asked this question in an interview. And after the interview also, I was unable to understand it. So as a last resort I had asked
the question here. I will remove the 3rd questions. Apologies for that.

Feel free to ask it, but in a separate question. Questions here need to be focused.


I can't wrap my head around the second impl block. In my understanding, impl is typically used to implement a trait/methods on a concrete type like a struct. However, what does it mean to implement method on a trait object?

dyn Trait is a concrete type, just like String or [u8]. Implementing methods for dyn Trait is not equivalent to a blanket implementation impl<T: Trait> T. The former is implementing methods that can be called only with the concrete type dyn Trait, while the latter implements methods generically for any type implementing Trait.
An example of impl dyn Trait in the standard library is Any methods, like is() and downcasting. They are not implemented generically, because that is not needed: their usage is always with dyn Any, because dynamic type erasure is the usage of Any.
A method implemented on dyn Trait can be called on a type implementing Trait, but only by first converting it to dyn Trait:
trait Trait {}
impl Trait for i32 {}

impl dyn Trait {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    // 1i32.foo(); // Error
    (&1i32 as &dyn Trait).foo(); // Success
}

On previous editions, this could be spelled as impl Trait which was even more confusing, but since edition 2021 you are forced to say impl dyn Trait.

Additionally, I'm confused about the role of lifetimes in this context. Could someone explain the concept of impl trait objects with lifetimes ?

A trait object, essentially, is a type-erased version of some type implementing the trait. But it can contain any type; and that type might have a lifetime. Consider the following snippet:
fn foo<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Box<dyn std::fmt::Display> {
    Box::new(s)
}

fn main() {
    let v = {
        let s = "123".to_owned();
        foo(&s)
    };
    println!("{v}");
}

Here, the trait object contains the lifetime 'a, because it contains a reference living that long. But there is no sign of that lifetime in the return type. If that lifetime wouldn't exist, this code would lead to use-after-free.
This is why trait objects contain a lifetime, which is the unification of all lifetimes inside the type they contain. The above snippet won't compile, because we don't mention that lifetime and 'static is assumed. The syntax to say that lifetime is dyn Trait + 'a. In conclusion, impl<'a> dyn Trait + 'a is really "impl dyn Trait including non-'static types".
